# Stop Scalatest suite after before

Tags: scala, scalatest

I´m using ScalaTest, and before I start the test I´m checking some resources.

I would like to stop the execution of the test before start if I notice that one of the resources are wrong.

There´s any way to say a suite that must not be executed after the beforeAll??
regards

Answer (score 1):

[CancelAfterFailure](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.CancelAfterFailure) will halt a suite on failure.  If that isn't sufficient for your needs you may need to write a custom fixture.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `assume` assertion.  From the [docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions):

> Trait Assertions also provides methods that allow you to cancel a test. You would cancel a test if a resource required by the test was unavailable. For example, if a test requires an external database to be online, and it isn't, the test could be canceled to indicate it was unable to run because of the missing database.